# Checking the presence of certain variables in a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm writing an Exploratory Data Analysis using R Markdown. First of all, I need to check the "sanity" of the input data set. Among the other check I perform, I need to check if at least one between the variables `var_in` and `var_out` are present in the dataset. If at least one is present, the other one can be computed from the first one. Thus, I want to check which of them is missing, and store its name in a character vector. If *both* are missing, the analysis is impossible and I need to exit, preferably throwing a meaningful error.

I cannot include the actual dataset on which the check is performed, because it's \$10^6\$ rows with confidential data, so I need to use fake data. The code, however, is as similar to the real code as possible.

```
# fake data
n <- 10^6
input_df <- data.frame(wind_speed = 10*abs(rnorm(n)), wind_direction = runif(n, 0, 2*pi),
                       var_in = NA, var_out = 3)

# nearly real code
missing_variables <- character(0)

var_in_is_missing <- all(is.na(input_df$var_in))
var_out_is_missing <- all(is.na(input_df$var_out))

if (var_in_is_missing & var_out_is_missing) {
  stop("both var_in and var_out are completely missing, so I cannot continue the EDA")
}
if (var_in_is_missing) {
  missing_variables <- c("var_in", missing_variables)
}
if (var_out_is_missing) {
  missing_variables <- c("var_out", missing_variables)
}
```

Note that according to the principle of early return, I put the stopping test before the other two. The code runs, but it doesn't seem that readable to me:

1. I test both `var_in_is_missing` and `var_out_is_missing` twice: this is definitely not going to impact notably the performance of my code, but it still feels useless
2. is it really necessary to use three separate `if` statements? Isn't there a way to do it in R in a more...compact way, without sacrificing readability?

Comment: An additional minor comment, in this situation you should use `&&` rather than `&`,  cleaner as you're not comparing vector, and this way RHS won't be tested if LHS is FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
tt <- function() {
  naI <- sapply(input_df[, c('var_in', 'var_out')], function(x) all(is.na(x)))
  if (sum(naI) == 2) {
    stop("both var_in and var_out are completely missing, so I cannot continue the EDA")
  } else {
    missing_variables <- names(naI[naI == TRUE])
  }
  missing_variables
}
```

I put the code into function for testing. Tests:

```
input_df <- data.frame(var_in = NA, var_out = 3)
tt()
#> [1] "var_in"
input_df <- data.frame(var_in = NA, var_out = NA)
tt()
#> Error in tt(): both var_in and var_out are completely missing, so I cannot continue the EDA
input_df <- data.frame(var_in = 3, var_out = NA)
tt()
#> [1] "var_out"
input_df <- data.frame(var_in = 3, var_out = 3)
tt()
#> character(0)
```

P.S. maybe you also want to add some kind of treatment if the one/both columns are missing in data.frame...

Comment: Very nice! Also, the way you wrote it, it's easy to generalize it if in the future I need to check for more variables. I'll probably replace `sapply` with `purrr::map_lgl` or something, but other than that, it's great. Only, I don't get your last point: "maybe you also want to add some kind of treatment if the one/both columns are missing in data.frame". I already added some action: I update `missing_variables` accordingly. What diid you have in mind?

Comment: @DeltaIV if var_in or var_out were not in the data.frame then the code wouldn't work. why `purrr::map_lgl`?

Comment: I mean, functions downstream get `missing_variables` as an input and process the data.frame accordingly. I'd rather have each function do one thing: this one only checks for missingness of these two "complementary" variables.

Comment: Ah, I got your point now, thanks. The variables *have to be* in the data frame. It's the result from an automated system. The system may not have measured anything because of sensor failures (i.e., variables are missing), but the file header (i.e., the column names) is fixed.

Comment: `purrr::map_lgl` because the output is a logical vector. I like the type consistency of the `purrr` functions: just a pet peeve of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility :

```
cols <- c('var_in', 'var_out')
missing_variables <- cols[!colSums(!is.na(input_df[cols]))]
if (length(missing_variables) == 2) 
  stop("both var_in and var_out are completely missing, so I cannot continue the EDA")
```

Let's unwrap the definition of `missing_variables` :

- `!is.na(input_df[cols])` creates a matrix of logicals indicating if elements are `NA` (`FALSE`) or not (`TRUE`),
- `colSums(!is.na(input_df[cols]))` sum the columns of this matrix, `FALSE` is coerced to `0` and `TRUE` to `1` so a column will be full of `NA` if and only if this sum is `O`
- In `!colSums(!is.na(input_df[cols]))`, `!` changes `0` to `TRUE` and any other number to `FALSE`, so we get a vector of logical indicating if the variable is missing (`TRUE`) or not
- `cols[!colSums(!is.na(input_df[cols]))]` subsets `cols` to keep only "missing variables"

Comment: Can you explain me what `missing_variables <- cols[!colSums(is.na(input_df[cols]))]` does?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer, let me know if it makes sense to you.

Comment: I had a mistake and a typo, now corrected! (needed a 2nd `!`)

Comment: The 2nd `!` is still missing in your answer.