# A series of yes-no questions to predict yes-no outcomes

Tags: performance, r

I have been writing R scripts for about a week. I have been writing code for 20 years. I have a series of yes-no questions that I hope to predict yes-no outcomes so I know the R-squared will be terrible but as long as the variable is significant I am fine.

Since I am creating a number with my yes-no questions the order makes a difference and I have 14 questions which I plan to turn into 8-bit numbers (121,080,960 permutations). This is taking about 88 hours on my desktop. I am looking for anyplace to optimize my code. I have read about Multi core/thread SNOW but that is beyond me right now without some help. I also know I can compile functions but my code is short and only see one place to do so.

Please review my code, any help would be appreciated.

```
library(data.table)
ffName = "Perms8bit.csv"
# Read table of 1s and 0s
Bin_Matrix <-read.table("LC_FR_F17BIN.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")

Perm_Best <- 0
holdR  <- 0
s<- Sys.time()
cnt <-0

# Read the file 121,080,960 permutations to test
# Originally read the file in blocks but benchmark testing
rawData <- fread(ffName, sep=",")

   for (cnt in 1:121080960){
        # create a table result x binary number
        Bin_num <- data.table(result = c(Bin_Matrix[,15]),numb = c(2^0* (Bin_Matrix [,as.numeric(rawData[cnt,1])]) + 2^1*(Bin_Matrix [,as.numeric(rawData[cnt,2])]) +
2^2*(Bin_Matrix [,as.numeric(rawData[cnt,3])]) + 2^3*(Bin_Matrix [,as.numeric(rawData[cnt,4])]) +
2^4*(Bin_Matrix [,as.numeric(rawData[cnt,5])]) + 2^5*(Bin_Matrix [,as.numeric(rawData[cnt,6])]) +
2^6*(Bin_Matrix [,as.numeric(rawData[cnt,7])]) + 2^7*(Bin_Matrix [,as.numeric(rawData[cnt,8])])))

    #linear regession
    linearMod <- lm(result ~ numb, data = Bin_num)
    ModSum <- summary(linearMod)
    theR <- ModSum$r.squared

    # Find the top R squared, result is 1s and 0s so R squared will not be high
    if (theR > .0175) {
        holdR = theR
        Perm_Best <- data.table(cnt = cnt,R = holdR,rawData[cnt,])

         #append a file with best fits
         write(toString(Perm_Best,nrows= 1),file = "RSQ.txt", append = TRUE)
      }


   }
print (Sys.time()-s) #benchmark
print(holdR)         # just to let me know its done
print (Perm_Best)
```

`Bin_Matrix` is a file with around 2,000 rows, header, and a bunch of 1s and 0s in csv form.  `RawData` is a  table with 121 million rows with the different permutations (examples:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9
...
14,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
14,1,2,3,4,5,6,8
```

Comment: Can you supply small example of your data objects `Bin_Matrix` & `rawData`? preferably in `dput` format, so we can copy/paste and test your code. Like in other questions, for example: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204469/checking-the-presence-of-certain-variables-in-a-dataframe/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, without the two csv files, we are not able to test your code... Maybe if you could show us the profiler output (see the example in `?summaryRprof`) on a few iterations, it would help. What I suspect is that it will show most of the time is wasted either in the `lm` fit, or in the `write` call. Here are suggestions to improve on both as potential issues:

## Alternative to `lm`

Since you are doing **simple** linear regression, i.e. regression with a single variable, there is a closed-form solution for the R-squared and it is fast to compute with R's built-ins:

```
RSQ1 <- function(x, y) {
   mx  <- mean(x)
   my  <- mean(y)
   mxy <- mean(x * y)
   mxx <- mean(x * x)
   myy <- mean(y * y)
  (mxy - mx * my)^2 / (mxx - mx^2) / (myy - my^2)
}
```

Compare this with your implementation

```
RSQ2 <- function(z) {
  linearMod <- lm(y ~ x, data = z)
  ModSum <- summary(linearMod)
  ModSum$r.squared
}
```

Here I test both functions assuming your Bin_Matrix has 1000 rows. Your mileage may differ depending on how many observations you really have, something your question does not yet provide:

```
n <- 1000
z <- data.frame(x = runif(n), y = runif(n))

RSQ1(z$x, z$y)
# [1] 0.0007529693
RSQ2(z)
# [1] 0.0007529693

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(RSQ1(z$x, z$y), RSQ2(z))
# Unit: microseconds
#            expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#  RSQ1(z$x, z$y)  111.707  120.8345  146.3035  126.5945  143.2855  689.371   100
#         RSQ2(z) 2531.381 2554.2105 2883.7659 2626.9020 2966.8550 5103.368   100
```

## Inefficient `write`

The way you are using `write` is inefficient in that every time it is called, it must open the file, move the filehandle all the way to the end, write a line, then close the file. If your R squared is improved upon very often, this could start adding up. You would gain by doing the following.

- Before your `for` loop, open a filehandle: `fh <- open("RSQ.txt")`
- Make `write` append to the filehandle: `write(toString(Perm_Best, nrows= 1), file = fh)`  (notice, there is no need for `append = TRUE` anymore)
- After the `for` loop, close the file handle: `close(fh)`

Can you please give these suggestions a try and let me know if it helps? If it doesn't, maybe provide the output of the profiler? I hope it helps, good luck!

---

P.S.: Regarding coding style, you might find this approach for computation  `Bin_num` a little easier on the eye; it should not have a significant speed impact:

```
idx <- as.numeric(rawData[cnt, 1:8])
bm  <- Bin_Matrix[, idx]
Bin_num <- data.table(result = c(Bin_Matrix[, 15]),
                      numb   = colSums(2^(0:7) * t(bm)))
```

Comment: Thank you flodel for the suggestions. I will try to work them in when the current run is complete. The Write() statement is not used very often. So far in 70 hours there has been one R-squared above the threshold. I should be able to report back by Monday as to the improvement in processing time.

Comment: Doug, I'd love it if you could report back on the speed improvements. If it did it for you, please consider accepting my answer.